# How to ignore gloabally the IntelliJ annotator for max line lenght (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

I've setup the max line lenght in the code editor settings to be 120 (and not the default 80), but I am still having the red underline in my IntelliJ editor that says:
`Avoid lines longer than 80 characters`:

[image]

Is there a way to ged rid of that?

I am using Intellij 2021.2 Community Edition

Comment: Do you use any custom plugins?

Comment: @y.bedrov I use plugins: Bloc, Dart, Dart Fast Imports, Flutter, FlutterJsonBeanFactory, JSON To Dart Class, Maven Helper

Comment: If you press Alt+Enter on highlighted text it should suggest to configure inspections.

Comment: I want to ignore that globally, not just in one line

Comment: You can disable this inspection via the link to edit inspection settings, disable it in the project profile or edit your global IDE inspections profile. Or change your code style settings by increasing the right margin. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html. Does it help?